# Trouble extruding complex shape from model

Tags: modeling, extrude

I am having some trouble adding the following geometry to my model:

[image: desired geometry]
[image: ortho view from other angle]

The problem in the picture is that the gray geometry isn't connected to the black part of the model. I'm doing some bevel work, and it needs to be connected. I tried using a knife project of the shape, and extruding it from the model. But I had trouble getting all of my faces to stay flat. It created weird artifacts. I also tried using boolean operations to connect the gray part to the model, but the boolean operation failed, and I couldn't figure out a way for that to work either. I am not sure how to solve this.

I feel like there is a better solution; everything I have tried so far has produced artifacts. Are there any modeling techniques for extruding this kind of geometry? Or is there some other way for me to attach the gray mesh to the rest of the model?

Comment: It *should* be possible to do with **Boolean** if these are different objects or **Mesh** > *Intersect* in Edit mode if it's one Object. **Boolean** could fail most likely because of non-manifold geometry, because in this case model isn't that complex another reason to cause that.

Answer (score 2):

You need a quad strip running along where the two meshes meet to get your result without artifacts.

I would suggest:

1. Dublicate everything and hide the original versions of both objects.
2. Use a boolean operation to union the two copies.
3. In edit-mode, delete everything but the edge where they meet. You should now have a face less object that just describes the cut.
4. Bring back the originals and join everything.
5. Delete faces around the seam and create new faces that connects to the real seam.
6. Bevel the seam a slight amount.

Both objects:
[image: Both objects:]

Unioned objects with all but seam selected.
[image: Unioned objects]

Original objects joined plus seam. Faces bordering seams deleted.
[image: original and seam]

Merged geometry. Not all faces are quads, some are pentagons. Try to avoid that (I was in a hurry).
[image: merged geometry]

Geometry in wireframe view with beveled seam selected
[image: Resulting geometry]

Same geometry in solid view. It turned out ok.
[image: Final result]

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is to join the meshes together first.

1. Select the bottom edge of the Rounded mesh and move it so it creates a gap between the 2 meshes.
2. Now add to your selection of edge from the mesh you want to join and hit <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>F</kbd>

**Note** You may want have to do some cleaning up after the operation. The operation don't usually give you clean result, unless both selected edges have the same amount of vertex.

Your mesh should now be weld together with new faces in between the edges.

The image show the a rough idea of how the loop cut should look like.

[image]

This is how the mesh will turn out with a Subdiv modifier.

[image]

Comment: I'm a bit confused. First, what does alt-f do? I haven't heard of this key before. I can't seem to find what it is. Also, it is very important that I get a sharp edge.

Comment: Take a look at this tutorial it has Alt F at about 4:25 https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=O0mkoMkEbc0

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out. I didn't know why I hadn't found this before. What I would still like to know, however, is whether or not this is the "best" way of doing what I'm trying to do. I don't so much want to know how to attach the geometry. Rather, I want to know what the best way to get the desired result would be. Are there any general approaches to adding more complexity to a model like this? How would an experienced modeler model what I am trying to do here? I'm sure there are many approaches, but I am just not sure what to do here.

Comment: The real issue here is that there are two faces that this thing needs to attach. It needs to attach to the bottom disc, and it also needs to attach to the cylinder shape behind it. I have to use exact measurements here, since I am modeling a real object that I have. The existing model has to keep its shape, except with the addition of the "tombstone". If it was only attaching to on piece, it would be much easier.

Comment: I guess the best way for you to learn this is to draw the running edge line on the picture of the model you are trying to create. It's not a difficult model, the only problem is that you may have limited experience in visualising in your head how to go about it. When I first started off in modeling, I always prepare a blown up image of the parts that I have difficulty with and sketch those edges in before I try to model them in 3d software.

Comment: You're saying you plan out your edges? Thanks. I'll have to consider this in the future.

Comment: Yes if you are beginning to learn modeling it's great to pick up any object in your possession, take a photo and draw mesh line around it , just to learn how to design the mesh flow around an object. It's one the most fun part of learning how to do 3d modelling. At least for me :) ... after awhile you no longer need to do so, you could easily see where all the edges need to be. Good luck.